# Is a partial outer join the same as a left join

Tags: sql, db2, outer-join

Is a `PARTIAL OUTER JOIN` in `DB2` the same as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in `SQL`.

For example, will the 2 queries below return the same data:

**DB2**

```
SELECT  somefields.01,  somfields.02
FROM     upplosc0, cipname0               
PARTIAL OUTER JOIN  cuno.01=cuno.02
```

**SQL**

```
Select
    A.somefields
    B.somfields

From
    upplosc0    A

Left Outer Join
    cipname0    B
On  A.cuno  =   B.cuno
```

Comment: Isn't a _partial outer join_ either a left outer join or a right outer join (but not a full outer join)?

Comment: @jarlh YES, you've right! PARTIAL OUTER JOIN is a LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN... by default (if not specified ) LEFT.

Comment: @Nifriz What's the DB2 platform and version where `PARTIAL OUTER JOIN` works?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I tried it on IBM i and doesn't work, but searching online, I found much articles talking about PARTIAL OUTER JOIN as LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN. I assume PeterH can use it on his platform/version

Comment: @Nifriz It doesn't work on Db2 for LUW ([joined-table](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059207.html)), and it seems that it does't work on DB2 for Z/OS as well ([Ways to join data from more than one table](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_joindatafromtables.html)).

Comment: PARTIAL is not a reserved word nor is it a system function in DB2 for i either.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such thing as `PARTIAL OUTER JOIN` in any dialect of DB2. Maybe you are getting confused because there is indeed a `FULL OUTER JOIN`?

The only choices for join are:

**DB2-LUW and DB2 for z/OS**

```
INNER JOIN
[LEFT|RIGHT|FULL] OUTER JOIN
CROSS JOIN
```

**DB2 for i**

```
INNER JOIN
[LEFT|RIGHT|FULL] OUTER JOIN
[LEFT|RIGHT] EXCEPTION JOIN
CROSS JOIN
```

Answer (score 0):

It's IBM's version of a left/right join, yes.

> Partial joins are also called left or right outer joins when only two tables are being merged. Since IBM® SPSS® Modeler allows the merging of more than two tables, we refer to this as a partial outer join.

From https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-modeler/saas?topic=node-types-joins